# How do I build a Linq Expression Tree that compares against a generic object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics, expression-trees

I have an IQueryable and an object of type T.

I want to do IQueryable().Where(o => o.GetProperty(fieldName) == objectOfTypeT.GetProperty(fieldName))

so ...

```
public IQueryable<T> DoWork<T>(string fieldName)
        where T : EntityObject
{
   ...
   T objectOfTypeT = ...;
   ....
   return SomeIQueryable<T>().Where(o => o.GetProperty(fieldName) == objectOfTypeT.GetProperty(fieldName));
}
```

Fyi, GetProperty isn't a valid function. I need something which performs this function.

Am I having a Friday afternoon brain melt or is this a complex thing to do?

---

objectOfTypeT I can do the following ...

```
var matchToValue = Expression.Lambda(ParameterExpression
.Property(ParameterExpression.Constant(item), "CustomerKey"))
.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Which works perfectly,now I just need the second part:

return  SomeIQueryable().Where(o => **o.GetProperty(fieldName)** == matchValue);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
    var fixedItem = Expression.Constant(objectOfTypeT, typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName),
        Expression.PropertyOrField(fixedItem, fieldName));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(body,param);
    return source.Where(lambda);
```

I have started a blog which will cover a number of expression topics, [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/).

If you get any problems, another option is to extract the value from `objectOfTypeT` first (using reflection) and then use that value in the `Expression.Constant`, but I suspect it'll be fine "as is".

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed.

Now to figure out exactly what is going on :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see so far it's going to have to be something like ...

```
IQueryable<T>().Where(t => 
MemberExpression.Property(MemberExpression.Constant(t), fieldName) == 
ParameterExpression.Property(ParameterExpression.Constant(item), fieldName));
```

While I can get this to compile it's not quite executing the way it is required.

Comment: Close; you need to build a LambdaExpression - see my post.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }

    public Func<T, TRes> GetPropertyFunc<T, TRes>(string propertyName)
    {
        // get the propertyinfo of that property.
        PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

        // reference the propertyinfo to get the value directly.
        return (obj) => { return (TRes)propInfo.GetValue(obj, null); };
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

        // fill with some data
        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "John", Age = 45 });
        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Michael", Age = 31 });
        personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Rose", Age = 63 });

        // create a lookup functions  (should be executed ones)
        Func<Person, string> GetNameValue = GetPropertyFunc<Person, string>("Name");
        Func<Person, int> GetAgeValue = GetPropertyFunc<Person, int>("Age");


        // filter the list on name
        IEnumerable<Person> filteredOnName = personList.Where(item => GetNameValue(item) == "Michael");
        // filter the list on age > 35
        IEnumerable<Person> filteredOnAge = personList.Where(item => GetAgeValue(item) > 35);
    }
```

This is a way to get values of a properties by string without using of dynamic queries. The downside is al values will be boxed/unboxed.